# Can I iterate through my df within a defined function?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes two numbers and makes an output. I want to apply that function to a specific column in my df for the first two rows, and then the next two, etc.

`function(df['foo'][0:2])` works, and the next group to be passed into the function would be `[2:4]`. How would I create a loop that would iterate through my entire df? Or am I not thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop that iterates in steps of 2.

```
for i in range(0, len(df.index), 2):
    function(df['foo'][i:i+2])
```